# Скрипты запоминают домен

Tags: modx

Проектирую сайт на CMS Modx. Явно нигде в коде не прописываю адреса сервера.
После переноса скриптов с одного домена на другой, обнаружил, что скрипты запомнили предыдущий домен.

С чем это связанно?

Ссылки обозначал везде так: `[[~1~]]` или `[[++site_url]]`
Тем не менее стили, и скрипты даже js, запомнили предыдущий домен.
Это что вредоносный скрипт или у Modx есть память? Кэш вроде чистил,
и вообще на чистую инсталляцию устанавливал систему.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, насколько я понимаю, домен помнит браузер. У меня когда я внёс сервер с сайтом в другой домен - то наступили проблемы с "регистрацией". Нужно в браузерах поудалять  память "паролей".

Comment: в разных браузерах, где я даже не тестил сайт. Меню, например, из базы формируется в виде списка линков. Тем не менее, линки ведут на домен первичный.

Comment: А домен у вас же подключен через AD? Сама AD даёт не тот список линков?

Comment: да, новый домен. На него проинсталлировал систему чистую. Скрипты шаблона, чанков и снипеттов скопировал с предыдущего домена. Ссылки формируются в виде [[~1~]] обозначений, что подразумевают собой переход на ссылки того же домена, где находится сайт. Тем не менее, идет переход на домен первичный. В .htaccess тоже все чисто, нет никаких переадресаций на домен.